# Capistrano3 on Webfaction - bundle not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3, webfaction

I'am using webfection for my rails project. When I run deploy, get some error

> SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host web412.webfaction.com: cd /home/USER/webapps/PROHJECT/releases/20140906100427 && bundle install --without development test exit >status: 127
>   cd /home/unrealm/webapps/minecraft_rating/releases/20140906100427 && bundle installl --without
>   development test stderr: bash: bundle: command not found

Many FAQ's say's -

"Set default_env", ok, setted

```
set :default_env, {
    'PATH' => "#{deploy_to}/bin:$PATH",
    'GEM_HOME' => "#{deploy_to}/gems",
    'RUBYLIB' => "#{deploy_to}/lib"
}
```

but it's doesn't work.

My deploy.rb

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute "#{deploy_to}/bin/restart"
    end
  end

  task :bundle do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "cd #{deploy_to} && bundle install --without development test"
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :bundle
  after :bundle, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Capistrano is unable to do the bundle install on the server. Please check the bundler